# Website animation different frame rate on different computers and browsers

Tags: jquery, css, animation, lag

I learn web development in school and we have a project right now where we are making a basic landing page. I want to make it a bit more fancy and add some animations. I use both CSS keyframes and jQuery.

But I have a problem. On my home computer (pc), both in chrome and firefox, the animations are super smooth. But on my school computer (macbook pro 2015), they lag a bit in chrome but it's okay. In Safari, it's like 2 FPS do any of you know the reason?

jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(window).scroll( function(){

        //fade in
        $('.watch1-text1, .watch1-text2, .watch2-text2, .watch3-text1').each( function(i){

            let bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
            console.log(bottom_of_object);
            let bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
            console.log(bottom_of_window);


            if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object - 500){

                $(this).stop(true, false).animate({'opacity':'1'},500);    
            }

        }); 

    });
//scroll
$("#learn-btn").click(function() {
    $('html, body').stop(true, false).animate({
        scrollTop: $(".watch-1").offset().top
    }, 750)
    return false
})

$("#more-btn-2").click(function() {
    $('html, body').stop(true, false).animate({
        scrollTop: $(".watch-2").offset().top
    }, 750)
    return false
})

$("#more-btn-3").click(function() {
    $('html, body').stop(true, false).animate({
        scrollTop: $(".watch-3").offset().top
    }, 750)
    return false
})  
})
```

Css keyframe example:

```
@keyframes fade-in-logo {
     0%    { opacity: 0; margin-bottom: 50px; }
     100%  { opacity: 1;  margin-bottom: 0px; }
}
```

Comment: please be more specific, whats lag? the fadeIn or the scrolling?

Comment: @mr.void Both fade in and scroll has a really bad frame rate. So it looks supet choppy.